# Is there a better way to implement OnModelCreating method in EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

we have a products class that implements DbContext. The OnModelCreating method has code like so:

```
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomProductMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustomProductDetailMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustProdCatMappingMap());
 modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CustProductSKUMap());

...
```

here the entities are added one by one.

I am sure there's a better way to do this either using reflection or using an IoC container.

Can someone show me an example so that I can implement it myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following query to get instances of types inherited from EntityTypeConfiguration or ComplexTypeConfiguration:

```
var maps = from a in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
           where a.GetName().Name != "EntityFramework" // skip EF assembly
           from t in a.GetTypes()                        
           where t.BaseType != null && t.BaseType.IsGenericType
           let baseDef = t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
           where baseDef == typeof(EntityTypeConfiguration<>) ||
                 baseDef == typeof(ComplexTypeConfiguration<>)
           select Activator.CreateInstance(t);
```

All you need to do after that is adding maps to modelBuilder configurations:

```
foreach (var map in maps)
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add((dynamic)map);
```

Keep in mind, I use `dynamic` keyword because activator returns instances with type `object`. So we need to call appropriate overload of `Add` method based on actual map type.